# Laravel5 Eloquent update value issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to update my database based on this simple if statement, however it's not quite working as expected. This if statement runs and the page is just returned back without any database changes or errors.

```
$reply = Question::where('id', $replyId)->get()->first();

if($reply->answer_id == 0)
{
    $reply->update(['answer_id' => 1]);
    return redirect()->back();
} 
else 
{
    $reply->update(['answer_id' => 0]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

If I die dump the `$reply` I can see the attribute i'm trying to change `"answer_id" => "0"`

Comment: $reply = Question::where('id', $replyId)->first();

Comment: Try $reply = Question::where('id', $replyId)->first(); $reply->answer_id = 1; $reply->save();

Comment: Yes that works, thank you make it an answer & I shall accept